# When running `npm version` scripts, how to prevent a new commit from being made

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

When I run `npm version patch`, a new commit will be made. I don't want it.

The [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version) is pretty vague. The flag I *guess* is relevant is `commit-hooks`, but I'm not sure how to use it. There's no examples.

I've tried different patterns, for example:

```
npm version patch --commit-hooks=false

npm version patch --commit-hooks false
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--commit-hooks` argument determines if [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) are run on the commit creation.

The command you want is `npm version patch --git-tag-version false`

> Tag the commit when using the `npm version` command. **Setting this to false results in no commit being made at all.**

Answer (score 4):

If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag. This behavior is controlled by `git-tag-version` (see below), and can be disabled on the command line by running `npm --no-git-tag-version version`.